# Converting Python unicode code point string to its actual unicode character

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, unicode

I have a dataset containing some some poorly parsed text that includes a lot of unicode characters (like `'a', '{', 'Ⅷ', '♞', ...`) that have been improperly converted to Unicode.

All of the backslashes are escaped, so every unicode escape sequence was interpreted as a `\` next to a `u` instead of a single character, `\u`.

More specifically, I have strings that look like this:

```
>>> '\\u00e9'
'\\u00e9'
```

And I want them to look like this:

```
>>> '\u00e9'
'é'
```

How can I convert the first string to the second?

Comment: Any chance that you are actually dealing with JSON data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish without importing another module.

```
input_string = '\\u00e9'
print(input_string.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode-escape'))
# output 
é
```

Comment: This will produce garbage if the input string contains actual (unescaped) non-ASCII characters, because `unicode-escape` interpretes them as Latin-1, whereas you encoded them with UTF-8. Check what happens with `input_string = '\\u00e9é'`: instead of `'éé'`, you get `'éÃ©'`. You should use `.encode('latin-1')` instead of UTF-8, which will either work correctly (for good input) or raise an exception (for problematic input), rather than producing garbage in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to identify  the string as hex

> classmethod fromhex(string)
>   This bytes class method returns a bytes object, decoding the given string object. The string must contain two hexadecimal digits per byte, with ASCII whitespace being ignored.
>   https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex

Next we need to convert the hex to Unicode

> bytes.decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="strict")
>   https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

So it would look something like this

```
char = '\\u00e9'

print (bytes.fromhex(char)[3:-1].decode('latin-1'))
```

Comment: I didn't know what encoding block you wanted to use so I just put utf-8, should work now. I feel this is easier to read then selected answer

Comment: `bytes.fromhex('\\u00e9')` raises a ValueError. And you should decode with UTF-16, not Latin-1 or UTF-8, without cutting off the 0s. Also, I don't think this is easy to read; in particular the slice `[3:-1]` is hard to grasp.